Real life examples of pseudo-metrics
Every mathematician knows that, given a set $X$, a metric is a function $d:X\times X \to \mathbb{R}$ that verifies
(i) $d(x,y)=0 \iff x=y$
(ii) $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$
(iii) $d(x,y)\leq d(x,z) + d(z,y)$
From these properties it is very easy to prove that in fact $d(x,y)\geq 0 \quad \forall x,y \in X$.
If we substitute (i) by
$d(x,x)=0 \quad \forall x \in X $
that is, if we allow that $d$ does not necessary distinguish points, then $d$ is usually called a pseudometric.
I was thinking about what happens when we remove properties from the definition of metric, and in possible examples where it may be interesting. I can imagine real-life examples of non-symmetrical distances (thinking of the distance between two points as the work needed to go from one point to another), but it is difficult to me to picture a example of pseudometric not related with higher maths but with real-life scenarios. Can you help?
Some thoughts: board games in which if you arrive at a certain box, you inmediatly jump to another. Also, wormholes and instant teleportation come to mind. I am not sure if what I though makes sense.

All sorts of ranking systems fall induce psuedometrics. Just because two players have the same rank it doesn't mean they are the same person. But the absolute difference between rankings (which would be the pseudometric) can tell a lot.

@freakish That is a great example, because I previously thought of a possible pseudometric as $d(x,y)= |f(x)-f(y)|$, with $f$ not necessary injective, but I did not realize that models the difference between rankings. Thanks a lot!

The measure of the symmetric difference of two measurable sets is a pseudometric. That gives you a broad family of pseudometric spaces, which can relate to real world scenarios with probability.

All seminorms are pseudometrics and various seminorms are used often in PDEs and related fields. For example, if $u(x,y)$ denotes the vertical displacement of an elastic sheet at the point $(x,y)\in\Omega$, then the potential energy of a given displacement of the sheet to second order can be written as
$$
E[u] = \int_\Omega u_x^2+u_y^2~dA.
$$
This is known as the Dirichlet energy and more or less motivated the study of variational characterizations of PDEs. If you consider the space $H^1 = \{u\in L^2(\Omega): \nabla u \in L^2(\Omega)\}$ then this is a seminorm and hence a pseudometric. Indeed, we can see that $E[c]=0$ for any constant function $c$. You can think of this as saying that the potential energy due to stretching the sheet does not change if you lift the entire sheet up or down by a constant amount.
If you restrict the function space in various ways, you can make this a genuine norm, but this seminorm is important because of its physical interpretation as an energy and also because the corresponding Euler-Lagrange equation of this functional is the Laplace equation $\nabla^2 u = 0$.

Similar examples often occur in analysis. The Lipschitz seminorm are another instance, very much related to the present one; there we take the $L^\infty$ norm of "a derivative", here it's the $L^2$ norm.

Yes, these are extremely common in functional analysis. Hölder condition is a similar sort of seminorm and there are tons more related to Fourier analysis, dispersive equations,  etc. For elliptic equations, it is common that the Lagrangian of the PDE can be interpreted as a sort of seminorm since the operator is positive definite
